# Python: Strange behavior of PIL and cannot install pillow with pip

Tags: python, pip, environment-variables, python-imaging-library

I try to run script for my TFT screen. When I start it within environment IT WORKS. So script is fine. When I start it outside environment I get:

`./test
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./test", line 5, in <module>
    from PIL import Image
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 60, in <module>
    from . import _imaging as core
ImportError: cannot import name _imaging`

i started to think that I have wrong version of PIL or Pillow, but both are uninstalled. pip show shows empty result for both.

When I want to install pip install pillow I get few screens of logs and errors (unlike other installed packages).

```
sudo pip install pillow
Collecting pillow
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/89/b8/2f49bf71cbd0e9485bb36f72d438421b69b7356180695ae10bd4fd3066f5/Pillow-5.1.0.tar.gz
Building wheels for collected packages: pillow
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for pillow ... error
  Complete output from command /usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-gMbMIp/pillow/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d /tmp/tmpxj0jEHpip-wheel- --python-tag cp27:
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7
  creating build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/SpiderImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/PdfImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/PcfFontFile.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/MspImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/GbrImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/XVThumbImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/ExifTags.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/JpegPresets.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/version.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/ImageShow.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/ImImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/ImageMath.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/ImageGrab.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/_binary.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/PSDraw.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/Jpeg2KImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/ImageChops.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/ImageDraw2.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/BlpImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/WalImageFile.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/BdfFontFile.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/JpegImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/ImageOps.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/ImageDraw.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/OleFileIO.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/TarIO.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/ImageTk.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/CurImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/BmpImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/PyAccess.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/McIdasImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/ImageSequence.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/ImageEnhance.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/IcoImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/ImageColor.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/PixarImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/SunImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/ContainerIO.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/PcdImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/ImageMode.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/ImagePalette.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/PaletteFile.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/TgaImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/GribStubImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/WmfImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/ImageFilter.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/MpoImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/DcxImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/SgiImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/IcnsImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/XbmImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/XpmImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/features.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/_util.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/DdsImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/ImageQt.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/ImageTransform.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/MpegImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/PsdImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/_tkinter_finder.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/PalmImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/ImageStat.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/FpxImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/ImageCms.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/PcxImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/GimpGradientFile.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/ImagePath.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/TiffImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/FliImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/BufrStubImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/GdImageFile.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/Image.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/GimpPaletteFile.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/TiffTags.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/MicImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/ImageFont.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/GifImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/FitsStubImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/FtexImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/ImageMorph.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/WebPImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/PpmImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/PngImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/ImageFile.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/PdfParser.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/ImageWin.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/ImtImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/IptcImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/FontFile.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/Hdf5StubImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/EpsImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
  running egg_info
  writing src/Pillow.egg-info/PKG-INFO
  writing top-level names to src/Pillow.egg-info/top_level.txt
  writing dependency_links to src/Pillow.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
  reading manifest file 'src/Pillow.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
  reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
  warning: no files found matching '*.c'
  warning: no files found matching '*.h'
  warning: no files found matching '*.sh'
  no previously-included directories found matching 'docs/_static'
  warning: no previously-included files found matching '.appveyor.yml'
  warning: no previously-included files found matching '.coveragerc'
  warning: no previously-included files found matching '.codecov.yml'
  warning: no previously-included files found matching '.editorconfig'
  warning: no previously-included files found matching '.landscape.yaml'
  warning: no previously-included files found matching '.travis'
  warning: no previously-included files found matching '.travis/*'
  warning: no previously-included files found matching 'build_children.sh'
  warning: no previously-included files found matching 'tox.ini'
  warning: no previously-included files matching '.git*' found anywhere in distribution
  warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
  warning: no previously-included files matching '*.so' found anywhere in distribution
  writing manifest file 'src/Pillow.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
  running build_ext


  The headers or library files could not be found for jpeg,
  a required dependency when compiling Pillow from source.

  Please see the install instructions at:
     https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html

  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    File "/tmp/pip-build-gMbMIp/pillow/setup.py", line 806, in <module>
      raise RequiredDependencyException(msg)
  __main__.RequiredDependencyException:

  The headers or library files could not be found for jpeg,
  a required dependency when compiling Pillow from source.

  Please see the install instructions at:
     https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html



  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for pillow
  Running setup.py clean for pillow
Failed to build pillow
Installing collected packages: pillow
  Running setup.py install for pillow ... error
    Complete output from command /usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-gMbMIp/pillow/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-FLskBf-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7
    creating build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/SpiderImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/PdfImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/PcfFontFile.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/MspImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/GbrImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/XVThumbImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ExifTags.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/JpegPresets.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/version.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImageShow.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImageMath.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImageGrab.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/_binary.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/PSDraw.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/Jpeg2KImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImageChops.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImageDraw2.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/BlpImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/WalImageFile.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/BdfFontFile.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/JpegImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImageOps.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImageDraw.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/OleFileIO.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/TarIO.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImageTk.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/CurImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/BmpImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/PyAccess.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/McIdasImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImageSequence.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImageEnhance.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/IcoImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImageColor.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/PixarImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/SunImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ContainerIO.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/PcdImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImageMode.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImagePalette.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/PaletteFile.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/TgaImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/GribStubImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/WmfImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImageFilter.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/MpoImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/DcxImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/SgiImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/IcnsImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/XbmImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/XpmImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/features.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/_util.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/DdsImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImageQt.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImageTransform.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/MpegImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/PsdImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/_tkinter_finder.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/PalmImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImageStat.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/FpxImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImageCms.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/PcxImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/GimpGradientFile.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImagePath.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/TiffImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/FliImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/BufrStubImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/GdImageFile.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/Image.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/GimpPaletteFile.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/TiffTags.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/MicImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImageFont.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/GifImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/FitsStubImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/FtexImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImageMorph.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/WebPImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/PpmImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/PngImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImageFile.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/PdfParser.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImageWin.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImtImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/IptcImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/FontFile.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/Hdf5StubImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/EpsImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
    running egg_info
    writing src/Pillow.egg-info/PKG-INFO
    writing top-level names to src/Pillow.egg-info/top_level.txt
    writing dependency_links to src/Pillow.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
    reading manifest file 'src/Pillow.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
    reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
    warning: no files found matching '*.c'
    warning: no files found matching '*.h'
    warning: no files found matching '*.sh'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'docs/_static'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching '.appveyor.yml'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching '.coveragerc'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching '.codecov.yml'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching '.editorconfig'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching '.landscape.yaml'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching '.travis'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching '.travis/*'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching 'build_children.sh'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching 'tox.ini'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '.git*' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.so' found anywhere in distribution
    writing manifest file 'src/Pillow.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
    running build_ext


    The headers or library files could not be found for jpeg,
    a required dependency when compiling Pillow from source.

    Please see the install instructions at:
       https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-build-gMbMIp/pillow/setup.py", line 806, in <module>
        raise RequiredDependencyException(msg)
    __main__.RequiredDependencyException:

    The headers or library files could not be found for jpeg,
    a required dependency when compiling Pillow from source.

    Please see the install instructions at:
       https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html



    ----------------------------------------
Command "/usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-gMbMIp/pillow/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-FLskBf-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-gMbMIp/pillow/
```

Possible solutions include (I believe):

1. Force a script run from command line to run in environment (but what to put in the very first line of the script?)
2. Force python outside environment to use environment packages so I do not have to double them (but how?)
3. Solve the pip install pillow riddle

Thank you in advance

Comment: Did you read https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html as the error message asks you to do? It pretty much explains both.

Comment: Also, what platform are you on? It's obviously some linux distro, but which distro comes with Python 2.7 and pip but isn't manylinux compatible? And, more to the point, does it have a python-pillow package? (You said "for my TFT screen", but a TFT screen is just a kind of active matrix LCD screen.)

Comment: I use raspbian.

Comment: Klaus D. I do not see any explanation for that error. I solved the problem temporarily with apt install python-pillow, but I have old version with it and function rotate works wrongly. I wrote that function temporarily by myself, but I would like to make it work some day :).

Comment: it is for external tft touch screen connected via SPI... so not normal monitor :).